# How to transform a 2d image into a fan-shaped image?

Tags: image, projection, projection-matrix

I'm working on some sonar images that are fan-shaped:

[sonar fan-shaped image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ksHy.png)

i have the data as a 1D array, and i was able to reshape it successfully into a 2D image:

[sonar 2D image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BgMGn.png)

The problem here is that I'm trying to understand how the software i'm using to view the fan-shaped images was able to transform the data into a fan-shaped image.

As you can see, the pixels at the bottom arc are more stretched than those at the center of the fan.

Is there a way to find the projection matrix that can help me retransform the 2D image into the same fan-shaped image as this software?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the mathematical treatise you were hoping for, but I can show you how you can generate such a fan-shaped image from your rectangular one, just using **ImageMagick** in the Terminal:

```
magick sonar.png -virtual-pixel gray -distort Arc 140  -flip result.jpg
```

[image]

---

You can also achieve the same results in **Python**, if you use [wand](https://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.6.7/guide/distortion.html?highlight=arc#arc) which is based on **ImageMagick**.

---

You can also read about distortions in general in an excellent [tutorial](https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/#arc) by Anthony Thyssen.